# onclick event handler not work

Tags: javascript, html

This is a example code in JavaScript: The Definitive Guide,6th Edition.

```
<button id="my button">click me</button>
<script>
var b = document.getElementById("my button");
b.onclick = fuction(){alert("Thanks for clicking me!");}; /*work well if I delete this parse*/
b.addEventListener ("click", function(){ alert("Thanks again!");}, false);
</script>
```

When I click the button, nothing happen.

Comment: You can not use spaces in id name . Rename id to 'my-button' instead and it should just work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## are you sure you write well?

1 - Remove space on id value: change id="my button" to id="mybutton".

2 - is not fuction, is function.

```html
<button id="mybutton">click me</button>
<script>
var b = document.getElementById("mybutton");
b.onclick = function(){alert("Thanks for clicking me!");}; /*work well if I delete this parse*/
b.addEventListener ("click", function(){ alert("Thanks again!");}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button id can't have a space between the words. Use an underscore instead like `<button id="my_button">click me</button>`

Also, in your function call for your onclick you spelled function wrong.

See JSFiddle for working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/us2dq8sz/

Answer (score 0):

Wrong spelling in this line

`b.onclick = fuction(){alert("Thanks for clicking me!");}; /*work well if I delete this parse*/`

`fuction` instead of `function`

Working version : https://jsfiddle.net/x46ugomj/